# Keeping Score in Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3

I honestly can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried every solution I can think of. I am honestly hoping it is something very simple. Anyway, this is my code that I currently have

```
@IBOutlet var tacScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var ticScore: UILabel!

var winCounter = 0

if gameState[combination[0]] == 1 {
  winnerLabel.text = "Tac Wins!"
  ticScore.text = "Tic:\(winCounter += 1)"
} else {
  winnerLabel.text = "Tic Wins!"
  ticScore.text = "Tic:\(winCounter += 1)"
}
```

I don't get an error at all, but when someone wins in my game, the score labels just change too `Tic:()` and `Tac:()`

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code suppose to be like this:

```
var winCounter = 0

if gameState[combination[0]] == 1 {
    winnerLabel.text = "Tac Wins!"
    winCounter += 1
    tacScore.text = "Tic:\(winCounter)"
}else{
    winnerLabel.text = "Tic Wins!"
    winCounter += 1
    ticScore.text = "Tic:\(winCounter)"
}
```

The reason here is that the expression will be doing after the string returned to the .text pointer. All you need to do is just count it up first, then update the label.

Comment: Thank you...Oh my gosh...I can't believe I was that ignorant...Thank you so much

Comment: Please mark it as an answer, and vote it up. Thanks.